# how i change the value of Ran? in migrate table N to Y in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

A Ran? value of N indicates that the migration has not ran and a value of Y indicates that the migration has ran.can anyone tell me how i change the value of Ran? column from N to Y ... when i run the command php artisan migrate:status following output show [Ran? value show N how to change in Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qETi9.jpg)
 i have created successfully Post model by this command php artisan make:model Post -m but after that when i run this command php artisan migrate to customize my table posts it show the following error [1 PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists") C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458 2 PDOStatement::execute() C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458 Please use the argument -v to see more details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rKMv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

after some struggle i have find answer of my question 
first of all you have to write  file read more at 
[Schema::defaultStringLength(191); in your app>appservisprovider.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1llo9.jpg)
and [delete mannualy existing all table from the selected database then run this command php artisan miigrate:fresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bw0N.jpg) you have all done this succefully